# When creating a trigger in MySQL, are there any alternatives to FOR EACH ROW?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to create an after update trigger that runs only once even if multiple rows have been updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-23-5-1-11

> In MySQL 5.0, all triggers are FOR
>   EACH ROW—that is, the trigger is
>   activated for each row that is
>   inserted, updated, or deleted.

However, see the following [hack](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2006/04/mysql-hack-emulates-before-statement_30.html).

Comment: I'm trying to break away from MS SQL SERVER but MySQL keeps giving me reasons not to.

Comment: @Ovidiu Pacurar - Sometimes you get what you pay for :).